# "Connection refused" when opening SSH session using paramiko.Transport

Tags: python, ssh, sftp, paramiko

A problem using Paramiko for SFTP connection.

I've tried the following:

```
transport = paramiko.Transport(sftpHost, 22)
myKey = paramiko.RSAKey.from_private_key_file(rsaKeyFileSpec)
transport.connect(username = sftpUser, pkey = myKey)
sftp = paramiko.SFTPClient.from_transport(transport)
```

I get a response:

> paramiko.ssh_exception.SSHException: Unable to connect to HOST: [Errno 111] Connection refused

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

It should be:

```
transport = paramiko.Transport((sftpHost, 22))
```

or

```
transport = paramiko.Transport(sftpHost)
```

---

The [`Transport` constructor](https://docs.paramiko.org/en/latest/api/transport.html#paramiko.transport.Transport.__init__) is:

```
__init__(sock, default_window_size=2097152, default_max_packet_size=32768, gss_kex=False, gss_deleg_creds=True)
```

> Create a new SSH session over an existing socket, or socket-like object.
>
> ...
>
> For ease of use, you may also pass in an address (**as a tuple**) **or a host string** as the `sock` argument. (A host string is a hostname with an optional port (separated by `":"`) which will be converted into a tuple of (hostname, port).)